# C# Linq dynamic where statements combining DataTable and given Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I know that there were posts regarding dynamic where clauses in c# linq, however, I'm a bit new with linq and don't think that the solutions proposed were relevant to my case.

The problem is as follows:
I have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. Each value in the dictionary represents a set of values. For example: for a given key "food" the value can be {"apple", "tomato", "soup"}.  In addition, I have a `DataTable` which its columns are the dictionary's keys.

**My mission is** to build a linq which its where clauses are build according to the dictionary. 
Thus, among multiple values, "or" condition will appear and between key's values, "And" or "Or" condition will appear.

I can't write it hard coded since it must change dynamically according to the keys found in the dictionary.

I don't really know how to concatenate multiple where clauses which may match my requirements.

Comment: Not sure what your question is.

Comment: any pseudo code of what you want?

Comment: Showing your existing code may help others in guiding you in the right direction towards a valid solution

Comment: assume that I would like to add a where clause to linq such as:
where (myDataTable[key1].equals(val1) or myDataTable[key1].equals(val2)) and (myDataTable[key2].equals(val3)...
etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of concatenating linq expressions you can use .Any(), .All() and .Contains() to achieve what you want.

```
var filters = new Dictionary<string, List<string>> { {"Food",  new List<string> { "apple", "tomato", "soup"} },
                                                     {"Drink", new List<string> { "tea"                    }}};

var table = new System.Data.DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("Food");table.Columns.Add("Drink");

table.Rows.Add("apple" , "water");
table.Rows.Add("tomato", "tea");
table.Rows.Add("cake"  , "water");
table.Rows.Add("cake"  , "tea");

//And: Retrieves only tomato, tea
var andLinq = table.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Where(row => filters.All(filter => filter.Value.Contains(row[filter.Key])));
//Or: Retrieves all except cake, water
var orLinq = table.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Where(row => filters.Any(filter => filter.Value.Contains(row[filter.Key])));
```

The Contains is equivalent to equals val1 or equals val2.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the answer. That's the most precise that I could pull out of your question.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> filters = GetFilters();
var filteredSource = GetSource();            
bool useAndOperator = GetUseAndOperator();

foreach (var filter in filters.Values)
{
    Func<myDataRow, bool> predecate = useAndOperator ? s => filter.All(f => f == s["key1"])
                                                     : s => filter.Any(f => f == s["key1"]);

    filteredSource = filteredSource.Where(predecate);
}
```

Also this code doesn't makes much sense but it demonstrates the principle not the complete solution and you should update it accordingly to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
However, that not what I meant. the dictionary can have many keys which holds values. I have to iterate through it and enlarge my where clause. In addition I have an enum which says whether between keys I use "or" or "and". For a given key, among its multiple values , "or" is used. Hard coded values are not an option. It must be generic.